# How to add a new entity to MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create an new  entity in crm

```
    OrganizationService_orgService ;
    var connection = CrmConnection.Parse(conn);
    _orgService = new OrganizationService(connection);

    Entity newEntity = new Entity("this_is_a_new_entity");
    Guid newEntityID = _orgService.Create(newEntity);
```

I wrote the above code where the `conn`  is the connection string in the format  which is correct (i checked)

```
  string conn = "Url=https://damnidiot.crm5.dynamics.com; Username=XXXXXXXX@damnidiot.onmicrosoft.com; Password=XXXXXXXXX;";
```

but when i run the code i get an exception `{"The entity with a name = 'this_is_a_new_entity' was not found in the MetadataCache."}`

i am asuming i got this error because my crm does not have defination for the entity `this_is_a_new_entity` .

Is it possible to retrive And update the  metadata cache of my MS CRM ?(I AM USING Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 )

Comment: Is that entity Exist in mscrm?

Comment: No that entity does not exists in MSCRM

Answer (score 4):

If you use `new Entity("new_entity_name")` you are telling the code that you want to create a new *record* inside the *already existing* entity named `new_entity_name`.

To create a new entity altogether you have to issue a [CreateEntityRequest (link to MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509014(v=crm.5).aspx)

```
// PART OF THE LINKED SAMPLE
CreateEntityRequest createrequest = new CreateEntityRequest
{
    //Define the entity
    Entity = new EntityMetadata
    {
        SchemaName = _customEntityName,
        DisplayName = new Label("Bank Account", 1033),
        DisplayCollectionName = new Label("Bank Accounts", 1033),
        Description = new Label("An entity to store information about customer bank accounts", 1033),
        OwnershipType = OwnershipTypes.UserOwned,
        IsActivity = false,

    },

    // Define the primary attribute for the entity
    PrimaryAttribute = new StringAttributeMetadata
    {
        SchemaName = "new_accountname",
        RequiredLevel = new AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(AttributeRequiredLevel.None),
        MaxLength = 100,
        Format = StringFormat.Text,
        DisplayName = new Label("Account Name", 1033),
        Description = new Label("The primary attribute for the Bank Account entity.", 1033)
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

To create new entity you should use [Create Entity Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createentityrequest.aspx). Your code creates **record** of this_is_a_new_entity.

Comment: @user4137130 Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by _heiarchy of entities_. In you case creating a entity in CRM is equal to create a table in data base, and your code tries to create a record in non-existing table.